# Can I get into a career that specialises in mathematics writing?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, writing

Ever since I learned about math writing in LaTeX, I have really enjoyed it.

Over the summer before my freshman year of college, I spent hours rewriting a few papers I had written in google docs (yes with the horrible math integration) in LaTeX. I am now a 2nd-year undergraduate studying to pursue a pure math degree (I especially enjoy number theory).

In all of my math classes, I write my homework up in LaTeX, even though my classmates write it by hand and finish their HW in half the time it takes me. Still, I really enjoy the way my final product looks. I don't get any extra points for doing this, I just really love proof-writing and especially finalizing it in a way that looks professional.

My question is this: are there any career routes that specifically focus on mathematical writing? Obviously, math researchers write their own papers, but I'm curious if there is something more to math paper writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could join a publisher. Math publishers will often use TeX. [Example advertisement](https://illustrativemathematics.applytojob.com/apply/PWVM8oHVWU/K5-Curriculum-Specialist) from a quick search.

> - Experience teaching or developing IM K-12 Math
> - Excellent stakeholder and project team communication skills.
> - Strong computer skills with cloud-based systems, especially Google Workspace applications, Learning Management Systems (LMS), Zoom, and Slack.
> - Comfortable with:
>
>   - Website editing/typesetting including basic HTML, LaTex, or another markup language.
> - Willing to learn:
>
>   - The IM Content Management System (CMS), Wrike, Asana.

The key word to search for would be 'typesetter'.